# eBayes() lmFit()

Tags: r, bayes

I am using the golub data set from R with the labels.

```
labelgb <- factor(c(rep("ALL",27),rep("AML",11)))

names(golub) <- labelgb
```

I need to use the empirical Bayes method in the limma package and calculate p-values for the golub dataset using the `eBayes()` function.

```
fit = lmFit(golub)
e = eBayes(fit)
```

In the `lmFit` function what does the design argument do and if its crucial for the golub dataset to supply the design argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The design argument for lmFit() specifies the hypothesis you want to test. Therefore, the need for specifying the design argument depends on what features of the data you are interested in. In general, if you just want to test wheather each gene's expression is statistically significantly different from zero ("gene is expressed"), you do not need to specify the design argument. But if you are interested in probably some more interesting questions, such as, which genes are differentially expressed between acute myeloid and lymphatic leukemia, the case for golub's data, you would want to use the design argument. However, this depends a bit on the format your data is in, e.g., if you do not have a matrix but an Eset, and the details are specified in `?lmFit`.

Let's make this a bit more concrete with an R example. First, let's prepare the data:

```
data(golubTrain)
golub<-data.frame(golubTrain@exprs)
labelgb <- factor(c(rep("ALL",27),rep("AML",11)))
names(golub) <- labelgb
golub2<-log2(golub)
```

Now you can run the analysis, and get the results back as follows:

```
fit3 = lmFit(golub2)
e3 = eBayes(fit3)
tab3<-topTable(e3, number=nrow(golub))
head(tab3)

                 ID    logFC        t      P.Value    adj.P.Val        B
4454 X67247_rna1_at 14.53575 312.9962 6.550200e-70 3.014425e-66 121.8814
4299      X56932_at 14.46206 309.1822 1.073836e-69 3.014425e-66 121.7695
4390      X63527_at 14.38663 307.4711 1.343127e-69 3.014425e-66 121.7182
4482      X69150_at 14.46165 301.2372 3.067454e-69 5.163292e-66 121.5248
4178      X16064_at 14.40904 297.0073 5.424950e-69 6.565047e-66 121.3877
4044      X03342_at 14.46298 296.4517 5.850332e-69 6.565047e-66 121.3693
```

This does not use the design argument, and if you check the design matrix (something that design argument takes), you'll see a single column of ones:

```
fit3@.Data[[9]]
```

There's one row for each sample in the data. The number one here means simply "calculate a mean of expression of each gene across all samples". This is what happens by default if you do not specify the design argument, and these gene-wise means are reported above in the `tab3`.

Now, if you create a design matrix using the sample labels, and fit the model again, the results change a bit:

```
fit4 = lmFit(golub2, design)
e4 = eBayes(fit4)
tab4<-topTable(e4, number=nrow(golub))
head(tab4)

                           ID X.Intercept.   labelgbAML        F      P.Value    adj.P.Val
X67247_rna1_at X67247_rna1_at     14.53506  0.002391612 49686.79 1.146729e-67 4.588478e-64
X56932_at           X56932_at     14.47956 -0.060446048 48887.88 1.577261e-67 4.588478e-64
X63527_at           X63527_at     14.39760 -0.037901053 48086.27 2.183257e-67 4.588478e-64
X69150_at           X69150_at     14.44936  0.042461703 46096.31 5.012637e-67 7.901170e-64
X16064_at           X16064_at     14.40982 -0.002686716 44591.63 9.627122e-67 1.066709e-63
X03342_at           X03342_at     14.45553  0.025736126 44471.63 1.015107e-66 1.066709e-63
```

The p-values have slightly changed from the previous result. If you check the design matrix:

```
fit4@.Data[[9]]
```

you'll notice that there are now two columns. The first is still filled with ones, but the second contains zeros and ones. Every sample in the data matrix still has one accompanying row in this design matrix. All the ALL samples are marked with zeros in the second column of the design matrix, and similarly all AML samples are marked with ones. This means that the second column allows as to compare each gene's expression between ALL and AML samples.

The results tables tab3 and tab4 above contain results for each genes "mean expression", but what you would probably be interested here, is the compasion. These results can be generated, e.g., as:

```
tab5<-tab4<-topTable(e4, number=nrow(golub), coef=2)
head(tab5)

                   ID     logFC         t      P.Value    adj.P.Val         B
1926        M31166_at  3.066467  8.874042 1.605943e-10 1.012547e-06 13.726167
1834        M23197_at  2.081156  7.763016 1.853314e-09 5.842571e-06 11.495201
5772 U22376_cds2_s_at -2.432758 -7.533722 3.793734e-09 7.011885e-06 10.822197
760         D88422_at  3.554800  7.545045 5.082449e-09 7.011885e-06 10.551131
3320   U50136_rna1_at  1.402700  7.411954 5.560575e-09 7.011885e-06 10.462576
4847        X95735_at  2.805740  7.357965 1.486150e-08 1.561696e-05  9.550583
```

These are now the genes that are differentially expressed between the ALL and AML samples. I suppose that would be the most interesting comparsion for these data.

I also suggest to consult the [limma manual](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/limma/inst/doc/usersguide.pdf) for further information on actual technical details.

If you are familiar with theory of linear models, the first analysis corresponds to a model:

```
y ~ 1
```

and the second to:

```
y ~ labelgb + 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much, thats the best explanation I have ever seen about lmFit(0. I really appreciate your time.