# How can to compare 1750 samples between 3 groups by R?

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have 1750 proteins  that I want to compare the expression level of them between 3 groups (cell-type) using R. How can I do it?

Comment: It really depends what "compare" means. Do you want to plot stuff, get quantitative comparisons or ...? For example, the `ggplot2` package is very useful for visualizing multivariate data sets. And if your have questions about the specifics of `ggplot2`, stackoverflow.com is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Bioconductor project produces software (add-ons for R) for bioinformatics. Bioconductor offers several solutions to your problem. Possibly the easiest one is to use the limma package (http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/limma.html). It has an extensive user guide that walks you through the basics of the analysis.

In addition, see the answer [eBayes() lmFit()](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66600/ebayes-lmfit) for a quick overview of the workflow and the functions in the limma package.

What you need to consider is the question you are interested in. These questions are coded in a design matrix. For example, if you have one control group (C), and two treatment groups (T1, T2), and you are interested in comparing both treatments with the control group, you might generate the following model matrix. But, before generating the model matrix, let's assume your data matrix (containing the expression values) contains the controls in the three first columns, then three T1 columns, and last three T2 columns. A vector (listing the groups in the same order they appear in the data matrix) containing the group information can be turned into a model matrix as follows:

```
# "group" vector
groups<-c("C","C","C","T1","T1","T1","T2","T2","T2")
design<-model.matrix(~groups)
design
  (Intercept) groupsT1 groupsT2
1           1        0        0
2           1        0        0
3           1        0        0
4           1        1        0
5           1        1        0
6           1        1        0
7           1        0        1
8           1        0        1
9           1        0        1
```

If you do not have a control group, but some comparison group anyhow, just specify it as the first group (alphabetically) in the groups vector. The model matrix will automatically use it as a baseline with which all others are compared.

This does a simple comparison of groups (T1 v. C and T2 v. C). If you have something more complex in mind, please elaborate your question a bit to address this.